BigQuery Window functions
I want to calculate a 10 day rolling sum. The problem is that the time is not regular, eg sometimes we have a couple of observation on the same date and then some dates are missing in between.
Mock data looks as following:



order_id
order_completed_at
order_amount
customer_id
date_diff_10_days
sum_10_days




ord_1
2024-05-01
1
aad_1
2024-04-21
1


ord_2
2024-05-01
5
aad_1
2024-04-21
6


ord_3
2024-05-05
10
aad_1
2024-04-25
16


ord_4
2024-05-15
15
aad_1
2024-05-05
25



My idea was to use a window function, together with sum(if(date_diff_10_days <= order_completed_at , order_amount,0 ))
select 
* ,
sum(if(
  date_diff_10_days <= order_completed_at 
  , order_amount, 0)) as sum_10_days
  OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id order by order_completed_at asc
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
from mock_data

The query returns a cumulative sum over all records and not only of records within a 10 days time window. Does somebody have idea how I can fix my query?

Use a calendar table to generate a fixed continuous range of dates.

I'm worried that this approach might end up in a performance issue: the table has a high number of customers with low number of orders.

I'm not sure your desired result makes sense, unless you don't really want a rolling 10 day sum.  Order 4 is 14 days after order 1, why would both of those be included together?

I created a sample query order_id, order_completed_at , order_amount and calculated the rolling sum for last 10 days.I dont have Big Query, so unable to test. I have used postgres as an example.
Fiddle
I have used additional dates to test scenarios in the fiddle, let me know
WITH rolling_sum AS (
    SELECT 
        o1.order_id,
        o1.order_completed_at,
        o1.order_amount,
        o1.customer_id,
        SUM(o2.order_amount) AS sum_10_days
    FROM orders o1
    JOIN orders o2
        ON o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id
        AND o2.order_completed_at >= o1.order_completed_at - INTERVAL '10 days'
        AND o2.order_completed_at <= o1.order_completed_at
    GROUP BY 
        o1.order_id,
        o1.order_completed_at,
        o1.order_amount,
        o1.customer_id
)
SELECT * FROM rolling_sum
  ORDER BY order_id;

Output


Thanks @samhita. For BigQuery we just need to change the date calculation of the last 10 days eg DATE_SUB(o1. order_completed_at, INTERVAL 4 DAY)

Thanks for letting me know :) I was thinking that you might need to adjust that part.

This should do it, too:
Inspired by this page in the BigQuery docs:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#def_window_frame
SELECT
  *
, SUM(order_amount)  OVER (
    PARTITION BY customer_id 
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(CAST order_completed_at AS DATE)
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  )                               
from mock_data


The syntax did not work in BigQuery 'Window framing expression must be a literal or parameter', do you have some reference in the docs?

The problem here is that Big Query has a different format for interval literals than the DBMS-s I know. Looking up BigQuery's docs, I have modified the query accordingly

In fact, compared to other DBMS-s, it seems to lack the possibility of using intervals as values for the RANGE BETWEEN subclause. So you convert a date value (casting a timestamp to date if needed) to a numeric value.
